# Measure or log eevee compile times?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, command-line

I am trying to troubleshoot some compile times on a complex setup. In order to do this properly, I need to be able to check how long it takes Eevee to compile in various different configurations (you can delete your shader cache to make it start from nothing). Is there any sort of debugging in the console or something I can turn on to get told exactly when compilation starts and stops?

I am aware that you can mouse over the compile bar and see the time. But you've got to keep your mouse over it, and it frequently freezes so I'm not sure if its even accurate.

Whatever info is being displayed when mousing over the compile bar must be accessible in some form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run Blender from a command line, you can add a range of [debug](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#debug-options) or [log](http://options) options as described in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/index.html).

The problem with this approach is that the specific timestamps you want may not be part of the available logging and debugging messages; but more importantly, turning them on may change the timings in ways that invalidate the results.

The usual technique for checking times like you want requires modifying the source code and inserting specific timing calls, that accumulate data and only report results at the end; or running Blender under a profiler and analyzing the results of the profiler.

Both of these approaches require recompiling and running in program debug and development environments.